# unable to get information within php tag to show

Tags: php, html, embed

I have tried multiple types of code. I ultimately have resigned to the most simple implementation because I have gotten nothing to work.  Not even the examples from w3 school. Instead of getting Welcome and my name, I just get welcome.  For the second line,  I simply get Your email address, without an email address next to it.  Both files are in same directory on Windows 10 machine.  I am also using firefox.

[W3 school reference](https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_post) 
My first file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Second File:

```
[Link to second file][2]<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have php installed? What version?

Answer (score 2):

Use `$_POST["name"]` and `$_POST["email"]` **OR** change the form method to GET.

If you send the form data via the POST method (`method="post"`), then you can access it in PHP through `$_POST['field_name']`. If you want to use the GET method, change the form attribute to `method="get"` (or don't specify it at all, because GET is default) and then access the data in PHP through `$_GET['field_name']`.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I will make sure that both methods are 'post'. Thank you.  Hopefully that works.

Answer (score 0):

Your using the post method with your form. The data is stored in $_POST instead of $_GET. Either change the method to get or use $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

The action you are making does not match your second file

Proper version

```
[Link to second file][2]<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this, however, it is not working.  I changed them both to a post method.  I also tried <?php phpinfo()?> and <?php phpinfo() ?> in order to check if the php interpreter is no longer working in this environment.  I got no information.

Comment: It should work, if it does not maybe you have some other problem, can you share the error log